# I am trying to alter the layout of a Dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to alter the layout of my Dash app, I want two rows, the first of which to have two columns, left column to have all dropdown and radio items, the second column to have 'fig2'. then row 2 to be a single column with 'fig1' i have coded the bdc row and col scripts however it seems I need a 'children' function. after searching I still cannot correctly code the 'Children' function. can any one offer any advice or assist me?

```
    app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
   dbc.Row([
   dbc.Col(html.Div(
                
  html.Label("Scope"),
  
  dcc.Dropdown(id="Continent1", options=[{'label': 'World', 'value': 'All'},
                                         {'label': 'Asia', 'value': 'asia'},
                                         {'label': 'Africa', 'value': 'africa'},
                                         {'label': 'Europe', 'value': 'europe'},
                                         {'label': 'North America', 'value': 'north america'},
                                         {'label': 'South America', 'value': 'south america'}], value='All'),
 
  html.Br(),html.Label("Data Input"),


  dcc.RadioItems(id="Data1", options=[{'label': 'Confirmed Cases', 'value': 'ConfirmedCases'},
                                      {'label': 'Confirmed Deaths', 'value': 'ConfirmedDeaths'},
                                      {'label': 'Stringency Index', 'value': 'StringencyIndex'}], value='Confirmed Cases'), 
  
  html.Br(),html.Label("Policy"),

  dcc.RadioItems(id="Policy1", options=[{'label': 'Not selected', 'value': 'All'},
                                        {'label': 'Staying at home', 'value': 'Stay at home requirements'},
                                        {'label': 'School closing', 'value': 'School closing'}], value='All'), width=4)),
 
  dbc.Col(html.Div(
  dcc.Graph(id="fig2",figure=line), width=4)),
      

  dbc.Row(
      dbc.Col(html.Div(
          dcc.Graph(id="fig1",figure=geo))))])])
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: TypeError: The `dash_html_components.Div` component (version 1.1.3) with the ID "Dropdown(id='Continent1', options=[{'label': 'World', 'value': 'All'}, {'label': 'Asia', 'value': 'asia'}, {'label': 'Africa', 'value': 'africa'}, {'label': 'Europe', 'value': 'europe'}, {'label': 'North America', 'value': 'north america'}, {'label': 'South America', 'value': 'south america'}], value='All')" detected a Component for a prop other than `children`
Did you forget to wrap multiple `children` in an array?
Prop n_clicks_timestamp has value Label('Data Input')

Comment: the error sign I get when running the code is above

Answer (score 0):

An `html.Div` has the roughly the following signature:

```
html.Div(children, id, **kwargs)
```

The `children` here can be either a single component (from `html` or `dcc`), or a list of components.

This is a valid way to use `html.Div` (add style to a single dropdown):

```py
# Explicit
my_div = html.Div(children=dcc.Dropdown(...), id='my-div', style={'height': ...})
# implicitly:
my_div = html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(...), "my-div", style={'height': ...})
```

This is a valid way to assign multiple components as `children` of html.Div:

```py
my_div = html.Div(id="my-div", children=[
    dcc.Dropdown(...),
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.Slider(...)
])
```

However, your app will break if you try to insert multiple components:

```py
html.Div(
    dcc.Dropdown(...),
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.Slider(...)
)
```

This is because Dash will think you are trying to assign a component to the positional arguments (i.e. `children`, `id`, `n_clicks`, etc.), and fail to correctly create your `html.Div`.